# parse XML using Python

Tags: python, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<WindowElement xmlns="http://windows.lbl.gov">
    <WindowElementType>System</WindowElementType>
    <Optical>
        <WavelengthData>
            <LayerNumber>System</LayerNumber>
            <Wavelength unit="Integral">Visible</Wavelength>
            <SourceSpectrum>CIE Illuminant D65 1nm.ssp</SourceSpectrum>
            <DetectorSpectrum>ASTM E308 1931 Y.dsp</DetectorSpectrum>
            <WavelengthDataBlock>
                <WavelengthDataDirection>Transmission Front</WavelengthDataDirection>
                <ColumnAngleBasis>LBNL/Klems Full</ColumnAngleBasis>
                <RowAngleBasis>LBNL/Klems Full</RowAngleBasis>
                <ScatteringDataType>BTDF</ScatteringDataType>
                <ScatteringData> 1, 2, 3, 3 
                             </ScatteringData>
            </WavelengthDataBlock>
        </WavelengthData>
    <WavelengthData>
        <LayerNumber>System</LayerNumber>
        <Wavelength unit="Integral">Visible</Wavelength>
        <SourceSpectrum>CIE Illuminant D65 1nm.ssp</SourceSpectrum>
        <DetectorSpectrum>ASTM E308 1931 Y.dsp</DetectorSpectrum>
        <WavelengthDataBlock>
            <WavelengthDataDirection>Transmission Back</WavelengthDataDirection>
            <ColumnAngleBasis>LBNL/Klems Full</ColumnAngleBasis>
            <RowAngleBasis>LBNL/Klems Full</RowAngleBasis>
            <ScatteringDataType>BTDF</ScatteringDataType>
            <ScatteringData> 555, 555
.......
```

How can I use Python to read `1, 2, 3, 3` in the ScatteringData element and change it to `5, 8, 8`

There are two elements called ScatteringData and only the first one is changed.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you always need to make the same change?

Comment: Something to get your started: http://www.travisglines.com/web-coding/python-xml-parser-tutorial

Comment: For a nice XML parsing interface have a look at [lxml's ElementTree](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html), that will get you started.

Comment: the actual data are quite larger (145 x 145) matrix, so I need to write a program to change it.... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at libraries that are available for working with XML in python. You could start here http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonXml

Answer (score 2):

If you have to deal with xml's I suggest you take a look at [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) .

They say that lxml is the most feature-rich and easy-to-use library for processing XML and HTML in the Python language. And it's faster and more robust than it's alternatives. And do search in SO for lxml and others, because there are plenty of suggestion in previous questions about which one to use.

```
from lxml import etree as ET

In [14]: root = ET.fromstring(datafragment)

In [15]: root.xpath('.//scatteringdata')[0].text='blah'

In [16]: print ET.tostring(root,pretty_print=True)
...
<scatteringdata>blah</scatteringdata>
...
```

if you have to make changes in more that one place, use a loop:

```
for i in root.xpath('.//scatteringdata'):
    i.text='smth'
```

Comment: Why are you recommending `lxml.etree` instead of `xml.etree.cElementTree`? They're nearly interchangeable. There are many places where one or the other is better for specific use cases, but if none of those cases are relevant, the fact that `cElementTree` is built in, while `lxml` requires installing a C library and then a Python module, is a pretty big win.

Comment: Agree to an extent. For me, if you need to work with XML and HTML the choice offered by lxml is the widest and most powerful. It's not just lxml.etree but lxml.builder lxml.html and so on. If you need all of that, lxml is the lib to dig into. If you don't, "buit in's" are a good alternative.

Comment: Agreed that lxml rocks in general. Just that it's not necessary for the `ElementTree` API.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using [beautiful soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Basically it allows you to just walk down to the data and modify it as you see fit.

```
import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(open("waves.xml"))
soup.scatteringdata.string = "5, 8, 8"
print soup.prettify()
```

Which outputs:

```
  ...
  <scatteringdatatype>
    BTDF
   </scatteringdatatype>
   <scatteringdata>
    5, 8, 8
   </scatteringdata>
  </wavelengthdatablock>
  ...
```

If you wanted to take a look at the data first you can use

```
originalData = soup.scatteringdata.string
```

and then process that as you will